# Why does onFocus on my React Native app not fire when i focus on a TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am building an android-tv application with react native and i have been having issues dealing with the onFocus on a Touchable Opacity. I expect **Focused** to be logged to the console when i focus on the TouchableOpacity but yet nothing happens.

```
<TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.channelView]}
        onPress={() => {
          setChannelPlaying(item);
        }}
        onFocus={() => {
          console.log("Focused");
        }}
      >
```

```
<TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.channelView]}
        onPress={() => {
          setChannelPlaying(item);
        }}
        onPressIn={() => {
          console.log("Focused");
        }}
      >
```

I tried using onPressIn, but it doesn't fire when i use the TV remote to navigate and focus on it.

Comment: There's no `onFocus` event for `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: Ohh really, what component can i use apart from ```TouchableOpacity``` that has ```onFocus``` prop?

Comment: `TextInput` component

Comment: wow, how then can i implement this focus feature on a component aside textInput?

Comment: TouchableOpacity inherits TouchableWithoutFeedback Props and it has onFocus prop as well

Comment: You can add ref to your component and fire ref.focus() to be sure your component focused. In this case you should see your log in console. Which RN version do you use?

Comment: Alright, i will try that, my RN version is ```0.70.5```